cannot launch shell (overflow attack example)?
I am trying this example from the all time classic Smashing The Stack For Fun And Profit
https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs513/2005fa/paper.alpeh1.stacksmashing.html
testsc.c
char shellcode[] =
    "\xeb\x1f\x5e\x89\x76\x08\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x89\x46\x0c\xb0\x0b"
    "\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\x40\xcd"
    "\x80\xe8\xdc\xff\xff\xff/bin/sh";

int main() {
int *ret;
    ret = (int *)&ret + 2;
    (*ret) = (int)shellcode;
return 0;
}

I ran this command
sudo bash -c 'echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space'

followed by
gcc -o a.out -fno-stack-protector -fno-pie -no-pie -z execstack testsc.c

But when I run
./a.out 

there is no shell, the program just exits. Any pointers?

All dirty hacks quickly turn obsolete whenever there's a change to the ABI, OS or compiler. Was that paper even written for a x86_64 ABI in mind?

Your linked text states: "We also assume we are working with an Intel x86 CPU, and that the operating system is Linux." Not exactly what applies to nowadays most common PCs.

You should use a executor like
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SHELLCODE_SIZE 0x1000

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    void (*shellcode)();

    shellcode = mmap(NULL, SHELLCODE_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANON, -1, 0);

    if(shellcode == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("[-] mmap");
        exit(1);
    }

    read(0, shellcode, SHELLCODE_SIZE);

    if (argc == 2) {
        shellcode += atoi(argv[1]);
    }

    shellcode();

    return 0;
}

Compile the executor:
gcc -o executor -fno-stack-protector -z execstack executor.c

and send your shellcode insade:
echo -ne "\xeb\x1f\x5e\x89\x76\x08\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x89\x46\x0c\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\x40\xcd\x80\xe8\xdc\xff\xff\xff/bin/sh" | ./executor

You can look here: https://github.com/voydstack/shellcoding/tree/master (is a friend haha)

Hi, thank you for your response, but what's the difference? what makes one work and the other one not work? (also it is not clear to me that it works, I tried to echo something in the new shell but nothing appears)

@user3602697 Modern systems use a feature called DEP (Data Execution Prevention) to prevent code execution from memory segments marked as non-executable. Typically, the stack and heap are marked as non-executable. mmap allows you to bypass this restriction by allocating a region of memory that is explicitly marked as executable. This ensures that the shellcode can be executed.

I see, thank you. Is there a way this can be done without the executor? Because I would like to implement and try out the stack overflow attack with the shell

I would assume, creating a program that actively prepares everything to invite an intruder into the own bed isn't exactly what a typical situation for a buffer overflow attack is supposed to look like.
